# External JS file engine -- manipulating db using node.js? PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, external

Admittedly, I'm new to some of this...

Building a website on a local server. It has a ton of JS function in an external JS file.

Site has a MYSQL DB. (I am still learning this).

As part of my calculations from functions in that external JS file, I want to update and/or read from that DB.

I have been trying to read up on node.js and trying to read up on PHP (still learning both), but I'm not sure if I'm sniffing in the right direction.

Do I somehow invoke functions from node.js from the external JS file? Do I somehow invoke the PHP (in the form of a function, I suppose) from the external JS file?

How does one typically do this?

I have definitely learned that this in the external JS file **does not do the trick**. First window appears, but second doesn't:

```
  //  Activate the node.js library for MYSQL access
alert("got here 1");
      var mysql = require('./mysql');
alert("got here 2"); // nope, this never pops up
```

Higher-level advice might be more useful than detailed in-the-weeds advice...? Still very new to this.

Thank you kindly!

-=-=-=-=-

self-muttering thoughts... I am using the external JS file to hold a bunch of functions that do all kinds of manipulation and conformation to the data that I collect on the front end:

```
<button class="ButtonOperation" onclick="DataLog(document.getElementById('DataWindow').value,'NE_AssembleOrder')">Log Data</button>
```

Am I eventually going to discover that I should instead port all of these functions over to a big PHP file instead?

-=-=-=-=-

Comment: For clarity, where are you running this "external JS file"? Is it something which is part of the web page, so loaded into the HTML document in the browser? Or is it something you execute on the server using NodeJS when responding to a request from the browser? it's not clear how NodeJS and PHP fit into the picture here...normally if you're part way into designing your application you'd already have decided at the start which server-side language you're going to use - it's a pretty fundamental decision.

Comment: "but second doesn't"...then check your console (browser-based) or terminal (nodeJS-based) window to see if there are errors. For clarity: you can't connect directly to a database from client-side (browser-based) JavaScript. Instead you would need to make a HTTP request via AJAX to the webserver, and then a server-side script (either nodeJS or PHP or A.N.Other Language of your choosing) would execute in response to that request, would read any input data provided in the request, query the database and return the result. Fundamentally in a nutshell, that's how web applications generally work.

Comment: ADyson writes "For clarity, where are you running this "external JS file"? Is it something which is part of the web page, so loaded into the HTML document in the browser?" Yes, it is loaded up when the HTML page is loaded up.

"Or is it something you execute on the server using NodeJS when responding to a request from the browser?" Nope -- I am only just now learning node in case it helps.

Comment: "it's not clear how NodeJS and PHP fit into the picture here...normally if you're part way into designing your application you'd already have decided at the start which server-side language you're going to use - it's a pretty fundamental decision." They are my explorations. In fairness, I am not sure if/how they fit, I have been led to believe that these technologies might allow me to manipulate the DB from that web page. I am porting this over from a VBA tool that I wrote under Excel.

Comment: " I have been led to believe that these technologies might allow me to manipulate the DB from that web page"...yes they do. Like I said, web applications are fundamentally client-server applications. There's client code (HTML, JS and CSS in the browser) and server code (a webserver such as IIS or Apache with modules loaded for languages such as PHP, Node, ASP.NET, Java or  dozen others). The client code generally handles the interaction with the user, and communication with the server (to upload and download data). The server code generally handles security, business logic and data storage.

Comment: Here's a fairly succinct explanation: https://blog.stackpath.com/web-application/ . If you google "how does a web application work" you'll get plenty more too. I suggest you start by understanding the environment and the fundamental architecture you're working with, and then you'll start to see how the various tools and technologies fit together, and therefore how to need to make use of them to meet your business requirements.

Comment: Web development is significantly different than desktop-only development, due (primarily) to the client-server model and the inherent statelessness of the HTTP protocol. You need to get the key concepts clear in your mind first, otherwise you'll either make an unholy mess, or entirely fail to implement anything of value.

Comment: You may find it's better to buy a book / go on a course and study the fundamentals of your chosen language / frameworks, plus HTML etc, first before attempting to write a real application. Your VBA knowledge will certainly have some value and make your progress faster, but there's still a big learning curve to overcome. P.S. if you're already familiar with VBA then you might find using ASP.NET with VB.NET an easier leap than JS or PHP. Plus the ASP.NET framework abstracts a lot of the basic headaches of web development away (although arguably sometimes adds other complexities in their place)

Comment: "The client code generally handles the interaction with the user, and communication with the server (to upload and download data). The server code generally handles security, business logic and data storage."

That is my understanding as well. I am fairly comfortable on the client side (I originally started writing this tool in HTML/JS) and I am fairly comfortable fiddling with MYSQL via the admin console.

Comment: "You may find it's better to buy a book / go on a course and study the fundamentals of your chosen language / frameworks..."

I have been crawling through several books, in fact. Including "for dummies" books. I have also been going through a few different online classes. As far as "chosen," I am not sure how to choose, per se. I am definitely not married to VBA, it was just one tool to let me launch this thing quick a year ago, but it's getting unwieldy. And it only operates under Windows Excel, so limited there, too.

Comment: yeah you can't use VBA for this anyway. I just mentioned VB.NET because it's a related language with similar syntax inherited from the Visual Basic family in the same way that VBA is. So you might feel a little more comfortable there. But then again it's a bit of a dying thing - C# is much more prominent in the .NET Core ecosystem. The choice can come down to various things - what kind of language you prefer (e.g. strong vs weak typing, preference for object-orientation), familiarity with similar languages/syntaxes, the environment where you want the finished app to run and be supported...

Comment: ..., language features, ease of integration, available community and other support, availability of open-source libraries, quality & price of development IDEs, tools and environments, and other things including just pure personal preference to a degree. Personally I've done a lot with PHP and a lot with .NET, and both have their upsides and downsides for different tasks and different working styles etc. I have a tiny bit of experience of other server-side languages. You maybe need to narrow it down to a handful of choices and do a bit of more in-depth research into the features I've listed.

Comment: "The choice can come down to various things - what kind of language you prefer (e.g. strong vs weak typing, preference for object-orientation), familiarity with similar languages/syntaxes, the environment where you want the finished app to run and be supported..."

Fair enough. Thus my exploring. Admittedly, I am new to this SPECIFIC bit. Been writing programs in various languages and tools since about '81, if you can believe it (insert list of crazy languages), but never did anything with databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, took a while before I better understood this. So, this is the answer that would have gotten me moving in the right direction (for any future reference):

The thing to understand is that for this project, you want to manipulate data to and from a database, which means that (at least for now, for the sake of simplicity), the key is to get your data into a package and send it up to the server, and then have a function running on the server take up the yoke from there.

The way to do that (old school), is with a form.

When you SUBMIT a form, all that data on the form is bundled up and sent to the server.

In this instance you have an index.html page, and that page will open a new page for each of the functions you're trying to track. Use JavaScript to pop open the window and then when you include the URL for the window, pop in a Popup_*SpecificFunction*.php file. (change *SpecificFunction* as needed)

So far, so good. ;)

Now, in that Popup_*SpecificFunction*.php, you will collect all your data under a single *form*. A good ol' HTML form, with a [SUBMIT] button. That very same Popup_*SpecificFunction*.php file also has a reference in the header, referring to the big main library of PHP functions -- which is a file sitting on the server.

That [SUBMIT] button invokes a *ProcessAllThisData* function -- which is on the server-side PHP file. In doing this, it sends all the data from the form -- *including a lot of data you include in hidden controls* -- to the serverside function.

And at that point, you are basically "on the server" with all your data, and then you can just code that function in PHP and manipulate the database and other stuff as needed.

Using the form was the thought-jump you needed, because prior to this, you've generally thought of forms as standalone data, but they can have actions associated with the entire forms.

You can still use JavaScript to do client-side stuff, but here's another thing that can trip a person up:

There is a difference between these two HTML items as far as whether or not you should use them to send data to and from the server, or whether or not you are just going to JavaScript something on that button:

```
<button></button>
```

and

```
<input type="button"></input>
```

You might have to experiment a bit to figure out which is which.

This was everything you needed to get you moving in the right direction.

Sincerely,

Future Me. :)